# how to resolve "WARN: AMQ212054: Destination address=examp is blocked"

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm completely new to Spring JMS. I'm running a Spring JMS simple chat application using ActiveMQ Artemis. After calling `send()` I'm getting this:

```
WARN: AMQ212054: Destination address=examp is blocked. If the system is configured to block make sure you consume messages on this configuration.
```

The code after `send()` is not getting executed. Please help.

Comment: Cut/paste your broker.xml, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple reasons that the broker might block messages from being sent to an address:

1. If the `<address-full-policy>` is `BLOCK` and the address has reached the configured `<max-size-bytes>`.
2. If the `<address-full-policy>` is `BLOCK` and the [`<global-max-size>`](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/paging.html#global-max-size) for all addresses is reached.
3. If the [`<max-disk-usage>`](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/paging.html#max-disk-usage) is reached.

My guess is that you're hitting #3. Therefore, I recommend you increase your `max-disk-usage` from `90` (i.e. the default) to `100`, e.g.:

```
<max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may get this error due to your Disk Space is full, so try deleting some of the unused data from you disk space.